# Check if Samba only works locally

Tags: ubuntu, samba

## Introduction

My intention is to make files accessible from my local network. (streaming videos/music, sharing files,...)

For this purpose I set up an Intel NUC with Ubuntu and connected it to my local network. Due to I want this to work with both OS X and Windows I read that Samba is the right choice in this case.

## Problem

Everything works like a charm! But I am not sure about the security and any possible internet traffic.

## Problem 1: Security

The only two security relevant things I did are the following:

- I added a user for authentication when connecting to the server
- I used the "host allow" and "host deny" parameters like this

  - host allow = 192.168.0
  - host deny = ALL

So am I secure from connections from outside with that setup? I simply don't want anything to be public. Everything should just focus on my local network.

## Problem 2: Internet traffic

Due to I also stream/share big files it would be interesting if there is any internet traffic that will lower my bandwidth on other computers in the network also.

## Question

So is there any possibility to check if my Ubuntu Samba Setup is secure against connections from the public side of the NAT?

Comment: I recommend you read a bit about the difference between a NAT and a firewall. Not understanding that difference will come back and bite you later.

Comment: I can't understand your second problem. But anyways, it is not okay if you pack multiple questions into a single one. Asking multiple questions is not a problem here. I suggest to remove the second question and ask as a completely new one - you will get probably much better answers as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably secure, but there is no guarantee for that.

The samba service runs as a process listening at least on the TCP ports 139 and 445. By default it accepts connections from everywhere.

Your host allow/deny parameters make only the authentication impossible on these ports, but they don't forbid the connections to your samba service, which will be so attackable by different methods (for example, DoS attack or for any possible sechole in your system).

On my opinion, the best and most simple thing which you can do, if you set up samba to listen *only on your internal network*. It can be done with the `interfaces` setting in your `smb.conf`. For example, set an `interfaces = 192.168.1.1/24`, if your internal IP is `192.168.1.1` on a /24 subnet.

As an alternative, you can change your firewall settings as well. It depends on your firewall. In case of iptables, an `iptables -A INPUT -j DROP ! -s 192.168.1.0/24 -m multiport -p tcp --dports 139,445` would deny every incoming connections to your samba service which originates out of your internal network.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thanks a lot for your detailed answer! I guess the "interfaces" solution is the one I was looking for. "Listen only to the internal network" is what I want. Thanks a lot for your answer!